# Is there any difference between Photon produced from proton and electron?

Tags: photons, charge, photon-emission

I know that accelerated charged particle produces Photon but is there any difference between photon produced from a positive and negative charge?

Answer (score 2):

Photons can only be distinguished from other photons by either their angular momentum or linear momentum. When charged particles accelerate, they can accelerate in two ways --they can change their angular momentum or linear momentum. The resulting photon has to carry the corresponding difference away as both angular and linear momentum are individually conserved. The sign of the charge does not come into picture and hence purely by examining the photon you cannot deduce the sign of the charge of the particle that was subject to acceleration.